# Bash Script with Timestamp to Custom Log File

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this simple script,

```
#!/bin/sh
TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
echo "$TIMESTAMP" /etc/init.d/nginx restart >> /usr/local/nginx/logs/mylog.log 2>&1
```

However, it only prints the time into my custom log file and and won't restart nginx. What am I missing? I guess it's very simple somewhere but I cannot figure it out. Would appreciate any pointers, suggestions, comments at all. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If under [tag:bash] consider `printf -v TIMESTAMP '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T' -1` instead of run fork to `date +"%Y...`

Comment: ... or even: `printf '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T restart nginx\n' -1 >> /usr.../mylog.log`

Comment: thank you for your input, that's an interesting one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `echo "$TIMESTAMP" /etc/init.d/nginx restart` writes the current time and the words `/etc/init.d/nginx` and `restart` into the log file.

If you want to restart nginx, you should do that as a separate command, naturally.

```
echo "$TIMESTAMP" >>/usr/local/nginx/logs/mylog.log
/etc/init.d/nginx restart >>/usr/local/nginx/logs/mylog.log 2>&1
```

or,

```
{ echo "$TIMESTAMP"; /etc/init.d/nginx restart; } >>/usr/local/nginx/logs/mylog.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks for adding working example!

Comment: Thank you so much! That really did the trip! I've tried two separate lines before, one with just echo "$TIMESTAMP" and everything else went to the second line but it didn't work.